# What is the easiest way to put an icon beside a centered button?

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

I have a button and an icon :

```xml
<Button Content="Hello" Click="MyHandler"/>
<Image Source="icon.ico"/>
```

I'd like the button to be centered in its container and the icon to be right beside it, like so :

[image: A button that is centered and an image next to it on the right.]

Whatever the size of the screen, the button and its icon should stay at the same distance from each other.

I tried with a `Grid` and a `StackPanel`, but I can't get a proper result.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the combination of `Button` *and* `Image` centered as one, you could use a `StackPanel`.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Content="Hello"
            Click="MyHandler"/>
    <Image Source="icon.ico"/>
</StackPanel>
```

If only the `Button` should be centered and the `Image` put next to it, a `Grid` could be used.

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Button Grid.Column="1"
             Content="Hello"
             Click="MyHandler"/>
    <Image Grid.Column="2"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Source="icon.ico"/>
</Grid>
```